# Checking constraints in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I want to check all the **constraints** of my schema. Is there any **mysql** query of viewing all the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;
```

This shows you the SQL statement necessary to recreate tablename in its current form. You can see all the columns and their types (like DESC) but it also shows you constraint information (and table type, charset, etc.). And to get only constraints use

```
select * from information_schema.table_constraints
where table_schema = schema()
and table_name = 'tablename';
```

Comment: I have created all the tables and now I am assigning the foreign keys. At the time of foreign keys assigning it is showing 'announcement_ibfk_1' constraint name. So i want to know where all the constraints are going in informational schema.